# How to add Graphic Card to Virtualbox using Windows XP

Tags: virtualbox, graphics-card

I'm using Windows 8.1, I have installed Virtualbox and Windows XP. But VirtualBox virtual machine does not recognize graphic card.
I'm using:
Windows 8.1 64bit
Nvidia GeForce GT 630
Intel i3

How to recognize the graphics card on Virtualbox? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Virtual box has it own graphic which use the real graphic card, so you can't define any other graphic card.

You can just change the memory of virtualbox's graphic like so:

[image: virtualbox graphic card configurations]

Comment: @skydanny, instead of commenting, you can vote me up!